# Как выбрать из таблицы информацию по категориям?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если имеется таблица, где вся информация поделена, скажем, на 2 категории, как с помощью $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `table`") извлечь только строки одной категории? Деление на категории в таблице происходит в специальной колонке, где каждой строке присвоена какая-то категория.

Comment: SELECT name FROM table WHERE СпециальнаяКолонка = НужнаяКатегория

Comment: @Aviko примите ответ, который больше нравится галка слева от вопроса)

Comment: У меня каких-то там очков не хватает

Comment: О_о для принятия ответа они не нужны. Точно на галку жмете?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `table` where `category`='selectedCategory'")
//selectedCategory - название интересующей категории
```

Comment: alienator был первый :)

Comment: Ув. knes я вам там хотел предложить скрипт написать, но вы не откликались, может не видели. Не хотите ли?

Comment: Где именно? Не видел. 234787433 - прошу.

Comment: у меня нет айсика, может в гуглчате?

Comment: =/ проблема к гуглу я до вечера буду пароль восстанавливать. Скайп?

Comment: а может я просто по электронке ТЗ вышлю да и все?

Answer (score 1):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table where имя_колонки='категория'");